# Count reapeted values

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table WHONET_ORGANISMOS with a column ORG, and this column presents some repeated values.

ORG
arc
ack
abc
abc

I would like to assing a consecutive value at the end of the reapeted ones.

And I want it to become like this

ORG
arc
ack
abc
abc1

I am trying with this query but is not working, could you help me?

```
DECLARE @conta INT
DECLARE @conta2 INT
SET @conta = 1
SET @conta2 = 1

WHILE (@conta>=1)
BEGIN
    UPDATE WHONET_ORGANISMOS
SET ORG = {fn concat (ORG, @conta2)}
WHERE ID IN
(
SELECT MAX(ID) 
FROM WHONET_ORGANISMOS 
GROUP BY ORG
HAVING count(*) > 1
);
    SET @conta2 = @conta2 +1;
    SET @conta = SELECT COUNT(*)(SELECT ORG, COUNT(*) TotalCount FROM WHONET_ORGANISMOS GROUP BY ORG HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like below to acheive your requirement:

```
I have craeted a sample table temp:
create table temp(id int,ORG varchar(10))
insert into temp values(1,'ack'),(2,'abc'),(3,'abc')


SELECT
    id,
    ORG + (CASE rno WHEN 1 THEN '' ELSE CAST((rno-1) AS VARCHAR(10)) END) AS ORG
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY ORG  ORDER BY id) as rno,
        id, 
        ORG 
    FROM 
        temp
) T
```

And the result is:

```
2   abc
3   abc1
1   ack
```

Is this something you are looking for?